# margin-left transition not animating

Tags: css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I want to make an element slide by manipulating the left margin.

I've got it working using jQuery `animate()` but want to improve performance using CSS transitions.

I'm using jQuery to add a new class to the element I want to slide but it doesn't animate - it just moves the element instantly.

Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d30oewxz/4/) showing the problem.

If you click the button labelled 'animate left', it uses jQuery `animate()` and works as expected.

If you click the button labelled 'transition left', it adds the 'slide' class the element but doesn't work as expected.

I've tried changing margins from auto to a fixed percentage, but it didn't help at all.

Interestingly, if you hit F12 and manually change the 'slide' class margin-left property from -100% to -50%, it animates!

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to add the slide class to the container, so no need for everything else that was in the click event.

```
$('.transition').on('click',function() {
  var container = $('.container');
  container.addClass('slide');
});
```

Also, prefer using translate transformation instead of margin. They're more performant for animations:

```
.slide {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

With those changes, the div 'slides' left: https://jsfiddle.net/d30oewxz/5/

Comment: the question was why margin-left not working, not to use translate.

Comment: Interestingly this seems to work with translate, but not margin-left. I'd say this answer is a nice alternative way to achieve the same thing. Unfortunately it does not explain why animating the margin-left does not work. Any ideas there?

Comment: I've accepted dejakob's answer as I was able to leave the margin as auto but none of the answers made the transition work without stripping out the dynamically added div, which I do need. The dynamically added div seems to be the reason the transition doesn't work though :( Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you create new DOM elements. Notice that the added  does not have `.slide` class attached to it.

Also, I would suggest avoiding having multiple elements with same id, like multiple `<div id="content">` your jquery generate.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you had was that margin-left had a value of auto. You cannot animate from an auto value. So I replaced it with 0px.

Also I removed the modifications made to the html by jQuery. Especially the .wrap() seems to cause additional issues.

**JS-Fiddle**

JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d30oewxz/6/

**html**

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container">
  <div id="content">
   THIS IS SLIDE 1
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.content-wrapper > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s linear;
    -khtml-transition: margin-left 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: margin-left 1s linear;
    transition: margin-left 1s linear;
}
.button {
    margin-top:50px;
}
.slide {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$('.transition').on('click',function() {
  var container = $('.container');
  //removed this part of the code
  $('.container').addClass('slide');
});

$('.animate').on('click',function() {
  var container = $('.container');
  container.wrap('<div class="content-wrapper" style="width: ' + container.outerWidth() + 'px;"></div>');
  var  direction = {marginLeft: '-=100%'};
  $('.container').parent().append('<div class="container"><div id="content">THIS SLIDE ANIMATES WITH JQUERY</div></div>');
  container.animate(direction, 1000, function() {
  });
});
```